# python: call a class from a script in a different directory and get function

Tags: python, class, path, sys

I have a script that I am currently working on, named **exp1.py** and it's located in

```
/project/exp1.py
```

In this script, I am trying to call a function named **computelikelihood()**, which is inside the class **Class()**, which is in script **method.py**,  in a different directory:

```
 /project/methods/c_CLASS/method.py
```

So, in my code in **exp1.py**, I do this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/project/methods/c_CLASS/')
```

Which gets me to the folder where **method.py** is located, but when I want to call the `Class()` from the **method.py**, so that I get the function **computelikelihood()**, that I actually want, I get error. I try this:

```
from method import Class
from Class import computelikelihood
```

But I get `ImportError: No module named Class`. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
This is how the `__init__` of my `Class` looks like:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self,e2wl,w2el,label_set):
        self.e2wl = e2wl
        self.w2el = w2el
        self.workers = self.w2el.keys()
        self.examples = self.e2wl.keys()
        self.label_set = label_set
```

Comment: just `from method.Class import computelikelihood`

Comment: You can't "import functions from classes." If `computelikelihood` is a static/class method, you can call it from `Class`, e.g. `Class.compputelikelihood(...)`. If it is a method, you'll need to instantiate a `Class` first.

Comment: @Brian Not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific? `computelikelihood` is just a function , but I don't understand what you mean by "static/class method" or "method". Or also by instantiating the `Class` first. Or how to use `Class.compputelikelihood()` in my `exp1.py` script.

Comment: @joasa It seems like you're not familiar with how classes work in Python. You may find the official [tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) helpful. If `computelikelihood` were just a function, you wouldn't need to reference `Class` at all.

Comment: @joasa don't take this the wrong way, but if you don't know what those things mean *then why are you using classes to begin with*? Those are pretty basic concepts for understanding what a class is.

Comment: As an aside, `sys.path.append('/project/methods/c_CLASS/')` is really not the way you should be handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to use a method from a Class, you should do so via the class. Do not import the function alone as it isn't intended to be used as such:

```py
from method import Class

Class.computelikelihood()
```

However, this only works if `computelikelihood` is a static/class method:

```py
class Class:

    @classmethod
    def computelikelihood(cls):
        ...

    # or

    @staticmethod
    def computelikelihood():
        ...
```

If it's an instance method:

```py
class Class:
    def computelikelihood(self):
        ...
```

You'll need to first instantiate an object of class `Class`:

```py
from method import Class

classObject = Class()
classObject.computelikelihood()
```

Comment: Your post makes the distinction between functions, methods, static methods, and class methods rather ambiguous, given that you include none of the syntax that makes these distinction. I've suggested an edit to help clarify this.

Comment: Thanks that solves the error that I had! However, I edited my question so that you see what arguments my `Class` takes, because now I have this error `classObject = GLAD() TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`. How can I define these arguments in my **exp1.py** file when i call the Class?

Comment: `def computelikelihood(cls):` isn't a static/class method. It is still an instance method as you've defined it.

Comment: @joasa that's a totally different question. In any case, you need to provide whatever parameters that class is expecting. You've authored this class, presumably, so you would know.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i don't think it's a totally different question, as my question is how to call a class from a script in a different directory and get the function i want. so i'm trying to call the class by using the same arguments as in `__init__`, but i need to define them, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @joasa no, this has **nothing to do** with your class being defined in another module. Again, don't take this the wrong way, but *you probably need to take a step back and read up on the basics of classes*. You presumably authored this class, so you had some arguments in mind when you defined the `__init__` to take arguments. What value do you expect those variables to have if you don't define them?

Comment: If you read my previous comment, I specifically say that i'm not sure how to define them...

Comment: @joasa that is entirely up to whoever wrote the class. If you define a function, `def foo(a, b): ...` then obviously, you had some arguments in mind, suppose `foo` simply does `return a + b`, then you would have had numbers in mind. The same with a class definition. No one can tell you what arguments the class you've written needs. That is *entirely up to the author*.

Comment: I'm not asking what arguments my class needs! There's major difficulty in our communication, sorry.

Comment: @Brian thank you for the edit! I responded relatively quickly and forgot the decorators. Thanks for the help!